# How to add an ImageView below AppBarLayout under CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I achieved this by adding `android:layout_marginTop="112dp"`, is there any other way to get my ImageView just below the `AppBarLayout` like we do in RelativeLayout?

Also, I want this `ImageView` to have same drop shadow as the `AppBarLayout` has so the image will appear as the part of the AppBarLayout.

And I want the `TextView` to appear below the Image in `LinearLayout`.

**Main Activity XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/under_tabs_triangle"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

**Fragment Main XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.dexbyte.player.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Please check this image:

[image]

Comment: Just put the `ImageView` *inside* the `AppBarLayout` underneath the `Toolbar`.

Comment: That will extend the background of the `AppBarLayout` which is not what I am trying to achieve. I have attached an image to show what result I want to get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I want this ImageView to have same drop shadow as the
>   AppBarLayout has so the image will appear as the part of the
>   AppBarLayout.

It can be possible by adding a `CardView` and the `ImageView` inside it or other ways for doing that but, if you want the both have the shadow, you'll probably need to remove `AppBarLayout` shadow since there will be shadow between the `ImageView` & `AppBarLayout` which won't look good.

> And I want the `TextView` to appear below the Image in `LinearLayout`.

`TextView` is actually showing in the right position because you have added:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

To the `ViewPager`. So, everything's fine. To achieve what you want, you can add:

```
android:layout_marginTop="30dp" <!-- Or more ... -->
```

To the `TextViewget` to get it done.